# Hibernate freezes/stands still during request when trying to flush: doesn't throw exception or error, just does nothing

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, c3p0

I am using spring 4.2.5, Hibernate 5.1.0.Final, c3p0 0.9.5.2, and postgresql 9.4. The problem has been occurring since I started using connection pooling (c3p0), before I was just using a basic spring datasource.

```
  [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143785 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections  - Collection found: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.bellPlatformCategories#193], was: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.bellPlatformCategories#193] (uninitialized)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143785 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections  - Collection found: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.configurableFields#193], was: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.configurableFields#193] (uninitialized)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143785 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections  - Collection found: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.descriptionFields#193], was: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.descriptionFields#193] (uninitialized)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143785 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections  - Collection found: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.productColorImages#193], was: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.productColorImages#193] (uninitialized)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143785 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections  - Collection found: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.productLists#193], was: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.productLists#193] (uninitialized)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143785 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections  - Collection found: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.productPictures#193], was: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.productPictures#193] (uninitialized)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143785 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections  - Collection found: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.productShopifyOption1Values#193], was: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.productShopifyOption1Values#193] (initialized)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143785 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections  - Collection found: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.productVariants#193], was: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.productVariants#193] (uninitialized)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143785 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections  - Collection found: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.ProductVariant.collectionProducts#1731], was: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.ProductVariant.collectionProducts#1731] (uninitialized)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143785 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections  - Collection found: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.ProductVariant.orderPieces#1731], was: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.ProductVariant.orderPieces#1731] (uninitialized)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143785 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections  - Collection found: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.ProductVariant.productPictures#1731], was: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.ProductVariant.productPictures#1731] (uninitialized)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143785 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections  - Collection found: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.ProductVariant.reviews#1731], was: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.ProductVariant.reviews#1731] (uninitialized)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143785 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections  - Collection dereferenced: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.productShopifyOption2Values#193]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143785 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections  - Collection dereferenced: [com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product.productShopifyOption3Values#193]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143785 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener  - Flushed: 0 insertions, 2 updates, 0 deletions to 5 objects
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143785 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener  - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 2 removals to 21 collections
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143785 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  - Listing entities:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143786 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  - com.thebrandsapp.pojo.ProductVariant{isPermanentlyInactive=false, regularPrice=0.00, dimensionUnit=null, stockQuantity=0, metaDescription=null, taxStatus=null, createdAt=Tue May 24 22:06:02 CDT 2016, inactive=false, reviews=<uninitialized>, inStock=false, id=1731, grams=0, sku=, barcode=, brand=com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Brand#60, brandProductVariantPosition=1, height=0.0, updatedAt=Tue May 24 22:12:11 CDT 2016, taxable=true, upc=null, weight=0.0, brandProductVariantId=21556778823, shortDescription=null, version=12, oldInventoryQuantity=0, requiresShipping=true, name=M, backOrdered=false, permalink=null, shippingClass=null, weightUnit=lb, purchaseable=false, orderPieces=<uninitialized>, inventoryPolicy=deny, collectionProducts=<uninitialized>, description=null, shippingClassId=0, metaKeywords=null, taxClassId=0, option3=null, fulfillmentService=manual, onSale=false, option1=M, option2=null, randomIntToKnowIfStale=9964169, shippingTaxable=false, compareAtPrice=null, taxClass=null, product=com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product#193, availabilityDescription=null, salePrice=null, backordersAllowed=false, length=0.0, productVariantItemPriceType=null, orderQuantityMaximum=0, orderQuantityMinimum=0, width=0.0, productPictures=<uninitialized>}
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143786 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  - com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Brand{ppNameFont=null, addresses=<uninitialized>, productListPriceFontSize=0, ppDescriptionHeaderColorHexString=null, plCellBorderWidth=null, ppDescriptionBodyFont=null, productPageTextFont=null, productPageHeaderFontSize=0, productPageSubheaderFont=null, productPageHeaderFont=null, shippingPolicies=<uninitialized>, id=60, plNameFont=null, plBackgroundColorHexString=null, productListTileBackgroundHex=null, brandStripeAccount=null, plLogoBackgroundTopColorHextString=null, version=20, productPageTextFontSize=0, productUsers=<uninitialized>, bellPlatformCategories=[], logoImage=null, ppDescriptionHeaderFont=null, ppNameFontSize=0, name=null, plBackgorundGradientTopColorHextString=null, legalBusinessName=null, ppDescriptionHeaderFontSize=0, productListPriceFont=null, plCellCornerRadius=0, brandStoreSetting=component[accessToken,accessTokenSecret,email,isInstalled,nonce,password,storeHash,storeName,userId,username]{password=null, isInstalled=true, storeName=the-main-main-main.myshopify.com, accessToken=afa83706ed66fcea805a92b6e20a7040, storeHash=null, nonce=1111, userId=null, accessTokenSecret=null, email=null, username=null}, isVerified=false, plCellBorderColor=0, ppPriceBackgroundColorHexString=null, plPriceFontSize=0, plBorderColorHexString=null, plFlowlayoutType=0, productListBackgroundImage=null, products=<uninitialized>, plCellBackgroundColorHexString=null, ppDescriptionBodyColorHexString=null, ppPriceFontSize=0, sellerUserAccounts=<uninitialized>, plCustomized=0, ppPriceFontColorHexString=null, ppNameFontColorHexString=null, productListNameFontSize=0, plNameFontColorHexString=null, productListNameFont=null, referralPercentage=0.0, ecommercePlatform=0, ppDescriptionBodyFontSize=0, brandOrders=<uninitialized>, plBackgorundGradientBottomColorHextString=null, productPageBackgroundColorHex=null, hasSignedUp=false, productPageSubheaderFontSize=0, plLogoBackgorundBottomColorHextString=null, ppPriceFont=null}
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143786 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  - com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product{descriptionFields=<uninitialized>, productShopifyOption1Values=[com.thebrandsapp.pojo.ProductShopifyOptionValue#769, com.thebrandsapp.pojo.ProductShopifyOptionValue#770], productListPictureURL=null, isPermanentlyInactive=false, description=, brandProductType=, productLists=<uninitialized>, createdAt=Tue May 24 16:40:09 CDT 2016, inventoryWarningLevel=0, inactive=false, productShopifyOption3Values=null, productVariants=<uninitialized>, id=193, productShopifyOption1=component[name,position]{name=Size, position=1}, sku=null, brand=com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Brand#60, randomIntToKnowIfStale=9964169, productShopifyOption3=null, productShopifyOption2=null, updatedAt=Tue May 24 22:12:11 CDT 2016, productColorImages=<uninitialized>, productShopifyOption2Values=null, availabilityDescription=null, ecommercePlatform=null, upc=null, version=23, productBrandProductId=6776062663, tags=, bellPlatformCategories=<uninitialized>, configurableFields=<uninitialized>, name=tshirt, inventoryLevel=0, productPictures=<uninitialized>}
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143786 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  - com.thebrandsapp.pojo.ProductShopifyOptionValue{product2=null, product1=com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product#193, id=769, value=M, product3=null}
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143786 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  - com.thebrandsapp.pojo.ProductShopifyOptionValue{product2=null, product1=com.thebrandsapp.pojo.Product#193, id=770, value=L, product3=null}
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143786 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue  - Changes must be flushed to space: "BellDatabaseSchema".product_variant
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 1143786 [http-nio-8080-exec-30] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL  - update "BellDatabaseSchema".product set product_availability_description=?, product_brand_id=?, product_brand_product_type=?, product_brand_product_created_at=?, product_description=?, product_ecommerce_platform=?, product_inactive=?, product_inventory_level=?, product_inventory_warning_level=?, product_is_permanently_inactive=?, product_name=?, product_brand_product_id=?, product_list_picture_URL=?, productshopifyoption1_name=?, productshopifyoption1_position=?, productshopifyoption2_name=?, productshopifyoption2_position=?, productshopifyoption3_name=?, productshopifyoption3_position=?, product_random_int_to_know_if_stale=?, product_sku=?, product_tags=?, product_upc=?, product_brand_product_updated_at=?, product_optlock=? where product_id=? and product_optlock=?
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Hibernate: update "BellDatabaseSchema".product set product_availability_description=?, product_brand_id=?, product_brand_product_type=?, product_brand_product_created_at=?, product_description=?, product_ecommerce_platform=?, product_inactive=?, product_inventory_level=?, product_inventory_warning_level=?, product_is_permanently_inactive=?, product_name=?, product_brand_product_id=?, product_list_picture_URL=?, productshopifyoption1_name=?, productshopifyoption1_position=?, productshopifyoption2_name=?, productshopifyoption2_position=?, productshopifyoption3_name=?, productshopifyoption3_position=?, product_random_int_to_know_if_stale=?, product_sku=?, product_tags=?, product_upc=?, product_brand_product_updated_at=?, product_optlock=? where product_id=? and product_optlock=?
```

my Hibernate.xml

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
h

ttp://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:properties/database.properties" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.thebrandsapp" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props> 
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">${jdbc.driverClassName}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">${jdbc.url}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">${jdbc.username}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">${jdbc.password}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>        
                <prop key="hibernate.cp30.min_size">1</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">0</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">100</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">100</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">2000</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">3</prop>

    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

<!-- transaction management stuff…. -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>


<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"
    proxy-target-class="false" />

</beans>
```

Comment: this is only the very end of the request's stack trace, if you need more, please let me know

Comment: 1) does it freeze immediately, or after some transactions have succeeded? 2) can you see how big the Connection pool gets, prior to the freeze? 3) can you get your JVM to dump thread stack traces, to see where things look to have frozen?

Comment: some flushing has already occurred successfully for the requests in which the freeze happen. I can now consistently recreate the problem. It occurs when I send off to requests that have the same DB queries in them in a very close time proximity to each other, so I assume deadlocking is the issue, but when researching it, an exception is thrown by hibernate for deadlocking and that is not the case in my situation, so there is no way for me to build in a retry mechanism, etc. Please let me know what you think the best course of action is. the requests work 100% whenever sent one at a time

Comment: Also please note that THE PROBLEM HAS NOTHING TO DO WITH C3P0 OR CONNECTION POOLING, I went back and tested it with the normal spring datasource and I got the same problem.

Comment: Also I HAVE NOTICED THAT EVERY TIME THIS OCCURS, THE LAST TWO QUERIES IN THE STACK TRACE ARE IDENTICAL, meaning that from two similar requests, two identical DB queries are being executed at the exact same time by Hibernate